# Tensoflow: Providing jacobians and hessians to ScipyOptimizerInterface

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying out the different optimization methods of `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` and some of them (e.g. trust-exact) require the hessian of the objective function.
**How can I use tf.hessians as hessian for `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface`?**

I tried to provide it with `hess=tf.hessians(loss,variable)` (which returns a list of tensors) but it needs a callable object. And if I input directly `hess=tf.hessians` I get `TypeError: hessians() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`.

If you have any examples of tf.gradients or tf.hessians used with `ScipyOptimizerInterface` it would already be super useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly supported by TensorFlow's `ScipyOptimizerInterface`  but you should be able to build a `hessian` function that will be passed through the interface and work over its head. `scipy.optimize.minimize` expects a function that recieves a candidate solution `p` (in the form of a 1D numpy vector) and returns the Hessian.

Therefore, define a Python function that receives a numpy vector `p` and evaluates the hessian for the solution defined by `p` using `sess.run(hess,feed_dict=feed_dict)`. 
`hess` is a tensor defined once by `hess=tf.hessians(loss,variable)` outside this function (so you won't define another `tf.hessians` operation with each function call).
`feed_dict` is a dictionary with your tensorflow variable as a key and a numpy array `p` reshaped to fit your variable's shape as a value. In case you optimize more than one variable in parallel, dig in `external_optimizer.py` to see how it packs and unpacks multiple tensors into a single vector (look for `_pack` and `_make_eval_func`).

Note that for most deep learning problems, calculating the Hessian is not practical because it's a matrix of the dimensions size(variable)xsize(variable) - which is typically too large. Hence the LBFGS optimizer is a more feasible second-order optimizer.